# Maximum number of isomorphic graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple graph on $n$ vertices, how many graphs are atmost there that are isomorphic to the given graph? Is it $\Theta(n^2!)$ or $\Theta(n!)$ which is number of permutations of rows or columns?

Comment: It can't be $n^2!$, there aren't anywhere near that many graphs on $n$ vertices.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $G$ be a graph on vertex set $V$.  I assume you are asking for the number of graphs on vertex set $V$ that are isomorphic to $G$.  The symmetric group $S_n$ acts on all graphs on vertex set $V$.  We shall apply the orbit-stabilizer lemma.  The number of graphs on $V$ isomorphic to $G$ is the size of the orbit of $G$ in this action.  The stabilizer of $G$ is the automorphism group of $G$, which we shall denote by $Aut(G)$.  By the orbit stabilizer lemma, the order of the group $S_n$ is the product of the size of the orbit of $G$ and the size of the stabilizer.  Hence, the size of the orbit is $n!/|Aut(G)|$.

Comment: so it is exactly $n!$?

Comment: @Turbo It depends on the graph, since $|Aut(G)|$ can be different for different graphs. For example, if $G$ is the complete graph then $|Aut(G)|=n!$, and so the size of the orbit is $1$. This makes sense: there is only one graph on $V$ isomorphic to the complete graph. On the other hand, if $G$ has no nontrivial automorphisms, i.e., $G$ is *asymmetric* (see Wikipedia), then $|Aut(G)|=1$ and there are $n!$ distinct graphs on $V$ isomorphic to $G$. So the answer *really* depends on the graph $G$.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is exactly $n!$, no $\Theta$ required. Every other isomorphic graph is uniquely determined by an isomorphism, which is a bijective function from the set of vertices to itself. There are $n!$ such functions.

Comment: This is not always right. For example there is only one complete graph on a fixed vertex set of size $n$. Not every permutation of the vertices will yield a distinct graph. But $n!$ is "probably" right in the sense that almost all finite graphs have no nontrivial automorphisms (Theorem 3.1 of these notes: http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/11-12/constraint/summerschool/nesetril.pdf).